# Ellipse button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, styles

Can i create an ellipse button without override all the template?

I have a template and style for TargetType=button and i want my ellipse button get these template.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this works, although it's not the most flexible solution:

```
<Button>   
    <Button.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}}">
                    <Ellipse Fill="White" />
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Button.OpacityMask>            
</Button>
```

Basically you just tell the button control to only show the parts which overlap with the ellipse in the OpacityMask, which is a visual brush in this case. For a quick and dirty solution this will work, although I do think that the best option would be to simply copy the default control template from [here (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) and adapt it slightly to your use. Put it in a resource file and keep it nicely separated like that.